# Regex split string in double quotes

Tags: java, regex, split

I have the following string I need to split by double quotes. below is the sample string

```
String raw = "\"AKINWALE JOHNSON ROTIMI                                \"   \"100000072      \"       \"1985"
                + "0217                         \"  \"                                                                                \"      \"0250000066               \""
                + "\"                                                         08035558619\"  \"22324902758    \"       \"NG0250002    \" \"9113985      \"";
```

When I try to split the string by double quotes, knowing that some quotes can be empty

I tried the following :  `String[] split = raw.split("\"(\\w\\s+|\\s+)\"");`

it is close but I seem to be missing something.

Comment: Please include your expected output?

Comment: Maybe you want to get all between pairs of `"`s? Like https://ideone.com/xkmjrY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply split it on `\\s*\"\\s*` which means `"` preceded by or followed by zero or more whitespace character(s).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String raw = "\"AKINWALE JOHNSON ROTIMI                                \"   \"100000072      \"       \"1985"
                + "0217                         \"  \"                                                                                \"      \"0250000066               \""
                + "\"                                                         08035558619\"  \"22324902758    \"       \"NG0250002    \" \"9113985      \"";

        String[] split = raw.split("\\s*\"\\s*");
        Arrays.stream(split).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
AKINWALE JOHNSON ROTIMI

100000072

19850217



0250000066

08035558619

22324902758

NG0250002

9113985
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/zmNzzg)

Comment: If we can narrow this down a bit further, your solution gives an array of 18 in size and I am expecting 9, it means that if I removed all empty string from the array, I would be left with 8, which means that from the raw string one of the values I am expecting is an empty string. can I do this with regex still or do I just loop through the output of the regex and remove all indexes with which their index is an even number?

Comment: @DaviesTobialex - You can use `String[] split = Arrays.stream(raw.split("\\s*\"\\s*")).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);` to get an array without empty strings.

Comment: If you want to retain the lines with just whitespace enclosed within quotes, you can use `String[] split = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"|\\S+")
              .matcher(raw)        
              .results()
              .map(MatchResult::group)
              .map(s->s.replace("\"",""))
              .toArray(String[]::new);`

Comment: this isn't the default `java.util.regex.Pattern` is it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Please check [this](https://ideone.com/WrZQy5).